# javascript .then not executing

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```js
function generateRandomTeams() {
  const prom = new Promise(() => {
    // ...
    console.log('teams', props.state.teams) // logs
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('here') // doesn't log
  })
}
```

I am essentially trying to execute the functions in `.then(() =>` after the first block (the one on top) has been executed. However, the function doesn't go into the "then" part.

To clarify, I did not return anything in the process.

How can I achieve the delayed promise call? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When do you expect the promise to get resolved?

Comment: Like, I just want to execute the things in `.then` after the first part (the one in `prom` has been executed. Was following along [MDN's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) documentation but didn't really know what went wrong

Comment: You never resolve it so then will not execute

Comment: As far as we can see you don't even define the resolve parameter to the executor, let alone call it. Maybe read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not resolving the `Promise` that's why it won't go to the `then` block. You either need to `resolve` the promise so that the `then` block will run or `reject` the promise so that the `catch` block will run. If you won't do any of the these then the promise will always be in the `pending` state.

*This image is taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)*

[image: MDN PROMISE IMAGE]

```js
function generateRandomTeams() {
  const prom = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      console.log("teams"); // logs
      res();
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("here"); // doesn't log
    })
}

generateRandomTeams();
```

If you want to run the `catch` block then you have to `reject` the `Promise`

```js
function generateRandomTeams() {
  const prom = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      console.log("teams"); // logs
      rej();
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("here"); // doesn't log
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("Error");
    });
}

generateRandomTeams();
```

Answer (score 1):

For `then` to you need to resolve the `promise`.

```js
function generateRandomTeams() {
  const prom = new Promise(resolve => {
    // ...
    console.log('teams') // logs
    resolve();
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('here') // doesn't log
  })
}

generateRandomTeams();
```

However note that then is not used like this most of the time, but like this:

```js
function GenerateRandomTeams() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // ...
    console.log('teams') // logs
    setTimeout(() => {resolve()}, 3500);
  });
}

GenerateRandomTeams()
.then(() => {
  alert("3.5 seconds later: Then executed");
})
```